# PHP cookies didn't work on host : 000webhost

Tags: php, cookies, host

I am coding a website and when i have upload this on the webhost : 000webhost. The function setcookie didn't work and block the  header location.
Can you help me please.

PS: The forum of 000webhost told me ti ask the question here.

Thanks

```
if(!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['mdp'])){
$req=$DB->getDB()->prepare("SELECT * FROM comptes WHERE (USER=:username OR MAIL=:username) AND confirmed_at IS NOT NULL");
$req->execute(['username' => $_POST['user']]);
$user= $req->fetch();
if(password_verify($_POST['mdp'], $user['MDP'])){
    $_SESSION['auth'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['flash']['success'] ="vous êtes connecté ";
    if ($_POST['remember']) {
        $remember_token= str_random(250);
        $DB->getDB()->prepare('UPDATE comptes SET remember_token= ? WHERE ID= ? ')->execute([$remember_token,$user['ID']]);
        setcookie('remember',$user['ID'].'//'.$remember_token . sha1($user['ID']. 'medicament'),time()+ 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 2  /*  temps cookie = 2 semaines*/ );
    }
    if ($user['role']=='client') {
        header('Location: account.php');
    }
    if($user['role']=='admin'){
        header('Location: admin.php');
    }
    if($user['role']=='cadeaux'){
        header('Location: cadeaux.php');
    }
    exit();
}else{
    $_SESSION['flash']['danger'] = "Identifiant ou mot de passe incorrect";
}
```

}
?>

Comment: Can you please add some your code into your question, from where you are trying to set the cookie.

Comment: Do they give you access to the error logs? If so are there any errors logged there? You say both cookie and header location don't work so it may point to an error higher up the code, what makes you sure it is those things being blocked?

Comment: This code work in local with wampserver

Answer (score 0):

I found another person on a forum suggesting adding:
`php_flag output_buffering on` 
inside the .htaccess file

change the PHP version in 000webhost setting is adviced to, but it caused code 500 error due to index.php file not automatically made.